# Two returns in a row

Tags: php, class

While reviewing someone's code, I meet two return in a row in several classes.
For example:

```
class class1{
    private $property1;
    final function __construct($property1){    
        $this->property1 = $property1;
    }
    private $property2 = true;
    function method1($bool){
       $this->property2 = $bool;
       return $this;
       return new class1();
    }
```

How does it work and what is this construction for?

Comment: It does not make any sense.

Comment: If you need to return two things, return an array containing that. `return [$this, new Class1()];`. Btw. Class names should begin with a capital character.

Comment: Your question is not clear ? two return never works. second return is written unnecessary.

Comment: It will always work the same as if you delete the `return new class1();` line.

Comment: and I agree it doesn't make sense. I was confused by how often such a construction was encountered in code. Besides, it was used in several variations.
Thanks for the answers, now I'm sure it's ridiculous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP only allows one return statement. Everything after the first return will be ignored. In you case the `return new class1();` will never be called.

From PHP documentation:

**If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call. return also ends the execution of an eval() statement or script file.**

You can check more  [here at php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)